# how to speed up mysql query with two order by filters

Tags: mysql

```
select * from mytable order by first_col desc, sec_col asc limit 1;
```

when using only one order by filter, the query finished rather quickly(a few seconds), but the above query took hours.  would a two column index speed this up? is there any way to speed up the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for now there is no solution to optimize "ORDER BY ... **ASC**, ... **DESC**". Mysql cannot create indexes with sorting order different than ASC.

ps: yes, I know it is a sorting order parameter in `create index` but it still doesn't work and was added to satisfy some ansi sql requirements.